# AWS iOS SDK v2 Files Upload to S3 issue

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload images to the S3, and for files that are less than 2 mb, it is ok, but for more than 2 mb, server return `Code=-1001 "The request timed out."`. Could someone explain how it is possible to handle this problem?

Code example below:

```
AWSS3 *s3 = [[AWSS3 alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration];
AWSS3PutObjectRequest *logFile = [AWSS3PutObjectRequest new];
logFile.bucket = bucket;
logFile.key = path;
logFile.contentType = [self contentTypeForImageData:self.userPicture];
logFile.body = self.userPicture;
logFile.contentLength =  [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.userPicture length]];
[[s3 putObject:logFile] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    NSLog(@"Amazon error : %@", [task error]);
   return nil;
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `initWithConfiguration:`, you must manually retain a strong reference to an instance of `AWSS3`. One way to accomplish this is to make it a property. Using `defaultS3` eliminates the need for this since the `AWSS3` class retains the strong reference to the default service client for you.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Yosuke Matsuda you was right with that, but seams to me AWS V2 for the iOS is now quite raw. In two 5s iPhones it is possible to upload files without any problem but iPhone 5 is still running with time exception.

Comment: i have same issue but i'm trying to upload image using AWSS3TransferManager but can't understand how to solve it.

Comment: @Vats, I also have the same problem. Have you found some solution for this issue?

Comment: @Shkatulo, unfortunately not.